# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null in ionic serve

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new in Ionic 2.0. I installed ionic and all necessary modules to create an ionic project. I typed this command in command prompt:

```
ionic start --v2 MyApp sidemenu
```

After this, project was created correctly. But when I typed `ionic serve` , I get the following error:

[image]

I have searched in Internet but found nothing useful. I have worked with Ionic 1 but never get an error like this. Any idea why this is happening? Thank you.

`ionic info` output:

[image]

Comment: what does `ionic info` output?

Comment: I add it to question @suraj

Comment: do you have any `content` names in your code (as a property)?

Comment: no need add images..paste the output..

Comment: I think no. It is just an example code and very simple actually. It has just two pages

Comment: can you show `package.json`?

Comment: try to do `npm install ionic-app-scripts@latest` https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/590

Comment: When I run `npm install ionic-app-scripts@latest`, I get `'ionic-app-scripts' is not in the npm registry`

Comment: I am getting the same error as above. It only started happening after I added entries to my `app.module.ts`. Perhaps there problem is here?

Comment: sry its `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

Comment: It solved for me too. Thanks man :)